# express 3 get session in all template

Tags: templates, session, express

I'm using express `v3.x`

before i was able to send a dynamic helper to **all** my template via

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  session: function (req, res) {
    return req.session;
  }
})
```

now in 3.x we got `res.locals`
but when providing a function it doesn't inject `req` param

ex :
`res.locals.session = function (req, res) { return req.session; }`

`req` is `undefined`

how can i handle that beside setting session in every `render` function ??

Answer (score 3):

Before `app.use(app.router)` and after any session middleware try:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.session = req.session;
  next();
});
```